# NoReverseMatch at /password_reset/done/

Tags: python, django, reset, forgot-password

I have just learned from this [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html) to reset password in django. But I am not able to resolve the the

> error:NoReverseMatch at /password_reset/done

```
 from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^password_reset/$', auth_views.password_reset, name='password_reset'),
    url(r'^password_reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_done, name='password_reset_done'),
    url(r'^reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$', auth_views.password_reset_confirm,
        name='password_reset_confirm'),

    url(r'^reset/done/$', auth_views.password_reset_complete, name='password_reset_complete'),
    ]
```

Comment: please add full error trace

Comment: I have added them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `password_reset_done.html` template is incorrect. It includes the following url tag which is causing the error.

```
{% url 'password_reset_confirm' uidb64=uid token=token %}
```

However that url belongs in the `password_reset_email.html` template which is rendered and emailed to the user.

The `password_reset_done.html` template should tell the user that the password has been reset and to check their email. The [tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html) you linked to shows a valid template, you have copied it incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

The main part of the traceback is:

```
Reverse for 'password_reset_confirm' with keyword arguments 
'{u'uidb64': '', u'token': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: 
['reset/(?P<uidb64>[0-9A-Za-z_\\-]+)/(?P<token>[0-9A-Za-z]{1,13}-[0-9A-Za-z]{1,20})/$']
```

Empty strings don't match regular expressions it the url. You have to call `reverse()` with proper `uidb64` and `token`. Do you pass them into your template context?

Comment: I've followed the same instructions given in this tutorial: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/09/19/how-to-create-password-reset-view.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help